# const_cast giving invalid behaviour

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

   const int a = 3;

   int& b = const_cast<int&>(a);

   b = 4;

   std::cout << " a is " << a << "," << " b is " << b << std::endl;

   std::cout << &a << "," << &b << std::endl;

   std::cout << " a is " << a << "," << " b is " << b << std::endl;

   b = 6;

   std::cout << " a is " << a << "," << " b is " << b << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Here is the output

a is 3, b is 4
0xbfadc17c,0xbfadc17c
 a is 3, b is 4
 a is 3, b is 6

**My question is how can two variables are having same address but different values?**

Comment: Because undefined behaviour.

Comment: `const int a = 3;` says that `a` is always 3, so `cout << a` can be simplified to  `cout << 3`. Apparently the compiler does that.